# Flow doesn't allow object that matches a stricter version

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

Consider the following ([live link](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBASghgOwObQLxQN5QLYEsEBcUA-ABQICu2ARhAE5QA+UAzsHfkgJQA0OcADyJlKNek1btOXKAF8AUAGMA9gjY4QAMQRR0pOohRF4yCDNQA+KCrXKANhAB0d5Un2Gz8+aEhQAclS0dCYoupg4+MKiQXzYglGB4go26nAhEEQBYsEeYVh4hFAADLHxUACMRUVy8thaCKRpHlxAA)):

```
type Range = { min: ?(number | string), max: ?(number | string) }
const myFn = (range: Range) => console.log(range)

type NumberRange = { min: ?number, max: ?number }
const aRange: NumberRange = { min: 0, max: 100 }
myFn(aRange)
```

Flow complains:

> Cannot call `myFn` with `aRange` bound to `range` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `max`.
>
> Cannot call `myFn` with `aRange` bound to `range` because number [1] is incompatible with string [2] in property `min`.

It seems to me `NumberRange` is essentially a subset of `Range`, so Flow should be fine with this usage. Is there a trick to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that objects are mutable, so `myFn` could do `range.min = "foo"; range.max = "bar";` and it would be allowed by the `Range` type, but then `aRange` would be a `NumberRange` with strings!

if you make the properties of `Range` covariant by adding a "+" before the property names, you're saying that `myFn` is not allowed to mutate those properties:

```
type Range = { +min: ?(number | string), +max: ?(number | string) }
```

[Try Flow](https://flow.org/try/#0C4TwDgpgBASghgOwObQLxQN5QNQFsCWCAXFAPwAUCArrgEYQBOUAPlAM7AOFICUANDlxwAHiQrU6jFu07ceUAL4AoAMYB7BByi4QAMQRR05BohQl4yCPNQA+KOs1qANhAB0TtUmOmrSpaEgoADkaegYLFENMbUIxCTCBIVEyeKllBy04CIgSEMlwnyisAmIoAAZEkRIARjKyxSUdfXIsnx4gA)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't plan on mixing the types of `min` and `max` you could make `Range` a Union Type instead.

```
type NumberRange = { min: ?number, max: ?number }
type StringRange = { min: ?string, max: ?string }

type Range = NumberRange | StringRange
const myFn = (range: Range) => console.log(range)

const aRange: NumberRange = { min: 0, max: 100 }
myFn(aRange)
```